# Ubuntu: Computer totally hangs, what logs should I check

Tags: ubuntu

I use ubuntu 14. About three days ago computer started hanging when I work - I even can't move mouse, so I press power button to restart the computer. It happens about 1-7 times an hour. For example I work in open office and it hangs. Or I work with console - it hangs. I can't understand what it can be and what logs I should check. What should I do?

Comment: Does only the graphical user interface hang, or are the consoles also not working then; did you try that?

Comment: Instead of hitting the power button, use the Magic REISUB trick to shut down cleanly, so you don't trash your filesystem. Hold SYSREQ and **slowly** type REISUB.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reisub